# Counting all characters by BASH character class

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-processing

I need to efficiently count every character of an arbitrary file by its character CLASS (as defined by the BASH man page); i.e.

> [[:alnum:]], [[:alpha:]], [[:ascii:]], [[:blank:]], [[:cntrl:]], [[:digit:]], [[:graph:]], [[:lower:]], [[:print:]], [[:punct:]], [[:space:]], [[:upper:]], [[:word:]] and [[:xdigit:]]

Once the file is processed, display on a single line the resulting counts for each, even when zero.

Web searches have not been fruitful in finding something along these lines.

The arbitrary file (`/tmp/f1.txt`) will contain a variety of diverse text/data.

I am not looking to process ELF binaries nor UniCode (or any form of multi-byte) content.

I am not concerned about line count (`CR` and/or `LF`), only fixated on accumulating a count of each 'character' in the target file by the above classes.

I intend for this to end up as a standard `function()` in a larger bash script.  Bash/sed/awk and the like are desired; while perl/python/ruby not so much.

Sample data files could be:

- Zero bytes, i.e. no content at all.
- A single character
- A single word
- Multiple words separated by whitespace
- Multiple lines interspersed with whitespace and/or CarriageReturns and/or LineFeeds.
- For multiline files there might not be a `CR` or `LF` to signify the end of the last line (yet all characters should still be counted).

Answer (score 3):

```
file=myfile
for class in alnum alpha blank cntrl digit graph lower print punct space upper xdigit
do
  printf '%7s: %d\n' "$class" "$(tr -Cd "[:${class}:]" < "$file" | wc -m)"
done
```

`ascii` and `word` are not standard character classes and are `bash` specific. `word` is `alnum` plus underscore, and `ascii` is characters 0 to 127, so you can do:

```
printf '%7s: %d\n' word "$(tr -Cd "_[:alnum:]" < "$file" | wc -m)"
printf '%7s: %d\n' ascii "$(LC_ALL=C tr -cd '\0-\177' < "$file" | wc -c)"
```

(note that the GNU implementation of `tr`, as of coreutils-8.22, won't work with multi-byte characters).

On systems using the GNU libc at least, you can also run:

```
$ locale ctype-class-names
upper;lower;alpha;digit;xdigit;space;print;graph;blank;cntrl;punct;alnum;combining;combining_level3
```

To find out the list of character classes that are defined in your locale.

Comment: `word` is not synonymous to `alnum` – “_” is `word` but is not `alnum`. http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=czZcwix0

Comment: @manatwork, you're right. Checking the bash code, it is indeed alnum+_, answer fixed accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a fun class!  What is it?

This will get you most of the way there; sed doesn't seem to support :ascii: or :word:, but:

```
for f in alnum alpha ascii blank cntrl digit graph lower print punct space upper word xdigit
do
  echo "$f: $(sed s/[^[:$f:]]//g b.txt | tr -d '\n' | wc -c)"
done
```

Where we use sed to strip out everything *except* the characters we care about, then delete all the blank lines, and just get the count of characters left over.

Should be relatively accurate, with the possible exception of +/-1 or off-by-a-factor-of-ten errors.

Comment: That doesn't work for `cntrl` or `space` since you're excluding the LF characters. Depending on the `sed` implementation, NUL characters may be an issue as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to be looking up what characters fit into to which class - probably you can figure that out and/or just consult the other answers. But this will give you an unequivocal representation of your file character by character without missing any:

```
 _c2o() { od -A n -t o1 -w1 -v | tr -dc '0-9\n' ; } 
 _c2o <file
 163
 150
 072
 040
 167
 141
 162
 156
 151
 156
 147
```

That's a function I use in a lot of different ways. Each line is a single bite expressed in octal format - though `od` is very configurable. But in this way you can very easily just `grep` or `sed` for your target values and implement a line counter. It's really a piece of cake. And it's very fast.

Ok, so I went ahead and did the classes anyway:

```
_classes() { set -- ${classes=alnum alpha blank cntrl digit graph lower print punct space upper xdigit}
        while ${1+:} false ; do
                printf %b $(printf '\\%04o\n' $(seq 0 127)) |
                tr -dc "[:${1}:]" | {
                        printf "$1='"
                        _c2o
                        printf "'\n"
                } ; shift
        done
}
```

Run the above and you'll get output like:

```
xdigit='060
061
062
063
064
065
066
067
070
...
'
```

From there, I'd imagine something like:

```
eval "$(_classes)"
for class in $classes ; do
    eval "$class=\$(_c2o <file | grep -c -F "$class")"
done
```

I need to figure that out a little better - but that just about does the whole job.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question though. As that gives octal representation of _bytes_ in the file, not _characters_ and you end up being further away from getting character class information.

Comment: Stephane, thats true - and i have an answer to that, or most of one, but i dozed off while finishing it up before i could post it. Ill have it up very soon.